# open dir() command is not working and not viewing files (php)

Tags: php

Whenever I click the files, they are not showing. All I received is, "Not Found. The requested URL was not found on this server." It used to work yesterday but when I tried running it again today, it didn't work.

```
function showopendirectory(){
            $dirlist = opendir("/xampppp/htdocs/PHP_Container");
            while ($filelist = readdir($dirlist)) {
                echo "<a href=filelist>" . $filelist . "</a><br>";
            }

            closedir($dirlist);
        }
<?php
    showopendirectory();
    ?>
```

Comment: Is that the complete directory name from the root of the server file tree?

Comment: yes, it was working yesterday but today it's not working anymore and I find that weird. Thank you for answering.

Comment: _"It was working yesterday..."_ - what have you changed?

Comment: I remembered moving my old xampp files but I didn't touch my current xampp files

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your problem is not the opendir but the Apache response because the error message "Not Found. The requested URL was not found on this server." is from your web server (Apache)

Comment: Thank you, it also says Apache/2.4.48 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1k PHP/8.0.7 Server at localhost Port 80

Comment: Check all Apache configuration, you can start by creating an empty index.html in the root of your Apache dir (check also vhost configuration if there are)